# Concatenate session to config/app.php setting in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, app-config, laravel-5

Hopefully this will be an easy question to answer, so as mentioned in my header how would I do something similar to the following in my config/app.php file:

```
'partial_year_img_src' => '/img/' . session('year'),
```

Comment: You should create a service provider that does a `Config::set('partial_year_img_src', '/img/' . session('year'))` after the rest of the framework has loaded. Laravel's session handler hasn't been loaded yet the first time the config files are read.

Comment: Hi @ceejayoz thanks for your reply, but I decided to create a Helper class as Javier suggested below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a recommended practice, but you could access the global PHP variable directly:

```
'partial_year_img_src' => '/img/' . $_SESSION['year'],
```

> Update: *As **ceejayoz** has commented, we can not access a value set in the Session object through the PHP Super Global because Laravel has its own implementation. So this solution is only valid if you have set the superGlobal with that value previously. *

Maybe you can create a Helper that contains a function that will return that path. Something like:

```
ImageHelper::getImagePath();
```

There you can access the Laravel Session.

Comment: Hey @Javier thanks very much for your quick reply, so how would you recommend I do it otherwise, as I would like to do it the correct way?

Comment: Maybe you can create a Helper that returns the image_path, like:

ImageHelper::getYearPath(). And there, you can use the Laravel Session Object

Comment: Aaaaah great that sounds like a much better approach, thanks a lot for your answer.  Maybe you should add that comment as an answer as I would prefer to accept that as the correct answer.

Comment: I've edited my answer including that recommendation. You're welcome!

Comment: I don't believe this will work. Laravel's `Session` class doesn't use the native `$_SESSION` storage, IIRC.

Comment: ceejayoz is right, the $_SESSION solution won't work if the session info has been written from Laravel.